# ggplot: color,fill and size in geom_point

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, point, fill

I simply want a scatterplot where each point is scaled by size and fill for different variables. I've read just about everywhere about this and I realize the default shape is hollow (I've changed it to 19, which is solid). I want the color and fill to be the same so each point has 1 color, 1 size, 1 x-y coord rather than the donut look its got going on. The separation of color and fill is frustrating me to no end... Here's the code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(period,freq))+
 geom_point(shape=19,aes(size=copies,fill=total_len,colour=total_len))+
 scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")+
 scale_colour_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

Comment: what's your data, and what's the problem?

Comment: For most point shapes in R, there is no fill, only color. (The exceptions are `pch` codes 21 to 25, which have both.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is

```
ggplot(data, aes(period, freq, size=copies, color=total_len)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

Comment: This was my bad, I realized the my points were overlapping (they were perfect circles within each other and I mistook them for fills). For anyone with similar issues I suggest messing with the size of the points. (i.e. scale_size(range=c(?,?)))